# Why is there an A natural in E major key

Tags: sheet-music

If you look at the following score you can that it is E major but that the A notes are natural.  Why?  You get points if you can name from what piece the music comes from.[image: score]

Also, if G is automatically sharped in E major then why does the author write a sharp sign next to the G below:

[image: score]

Comment: Isn't this piece in C# minor rather than E major?

Comment: Is this a joke? You're giving out bonus points for people to track down the Moonlight Sonata to read bar 18 where G natural was used making sensible the courtesy accidental G# in bar 19. Hint: if this is a serious question, don't try playing guessing games about the piece of music.

Comment: I wasn't going to down vote until I saw you selected an answer than doesn't even answer the question. Down voting to maintain some sense of quality here.

Answer (score 7):

This is Beethoven op.27 No.2, commonly called the 'Moonlight Sonata'.   To answer your question we need to show a bit more context.

Here's your first example, (in another edition where the editor actually decides NOT to use a cautionary A natural).  But the reason he might have done so is the A sharp in the preceding bar.

[image]

Here's the second one.  The cautionary A natural in the 5th bar treble is because of the A sharp two bars previously. The G sharp in the 4th bar bass is because of the G natural in the preceding bar.

[image]

Neither are strictly necessary.  Both might be considered helpful.  As mentioned, the editor of my version only thought one of them was worth putting in.  I can see why.  He's treating the melody and the accompanying triplets as separate voices.  He feels a a cautionary accidental is rated only when the preceding one is in the same voice.

Oh, and it's in C# minor, not E major.

Answer (score 5):

It's in C♯ minor rather than E major. The author probably didn't put in the accidentals asked about. It was more likely the type setter. As Laurence says, there are versions without those accidentals.

As so many other 'unexplainable' accidentals, these are *cautionary* or *courtesy* accidentals which are there to remind  players that a previous changed note has now in fact returned to the one in the key signature. The barline after any accidental will automatically cancel that accidental in any case, but sometimes it's felt that an extra reminder won't go amiss. They're often put in parentheses, which does make more sense. It's as if someone's saying 'yes, I know you're aware, but here's a little reminder anyway'.

Comment: What's the difference between c sharp minor and e major?

Comment: While the number of sharps in the key signature is the same, the tonics are different, usually different notes are played, and the whole sonorities and harmonies are not the same.

Comment: @logic1976  There are 3 "standard" minors: natural,  melodic, and harmonic.  The harmonic puts the 7th back into major position, but by tradition that is only indicated with accidentals, not in the key sig.  The melodic is different going up or going down, so it has to use accidentals.